# Why is $a^i_jA^j_k=\delta^i_ka$ valid

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, tensors, index-notation, kronecker-delta

On pg21. of Textbook of Tensor Calculus and Differential Geometry (Nayak), I've come across the following identity:
$$a^i_j A^j_k=\delta^i_k a \tag{1}$$
where $A^j_k$ are components of the cofactor matrix and a is the determinant.

I do not see how the RHS $\delta^i_k=0$ holds when $i=k$ on the LHS .

As an example let $[a^i_j]$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix, $i,j,k=1,2$. Then by taking $i=1$ and $k=2$
we have
$$a^1_1A^1_2+a^1_2A^2_2=-a^1_1a^2_1+a^1_2a^1_1 \neq \delta^1_2a=0 \tag{2}$$
Can someone please explain what has gone wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps you mean $\delta^i_k = 0$ holds when $i \neq 1$ on the LHS

Comment: Perhaps $A^j_k$ is instead supposed to be the adjugate, i.e. the transpose of the cofactor matrix.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think the author made  $(1)$ a general statement, and that $a^i_jA^j_i=a$ (no sum over i), so it is the perhaps the cofactor matrix?

Comment: $A_k^{j}$ can not be the cofactor matrix, it's the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix).